# Checked first modifier

Tags: expresso-store, expresso

I'm outputting modifiers as radio field but how could I target the first modifier so that it is checked.

```
{modifier_options}
    <div class="large-6 columns">
        <label><input type="radio" name="{modifier_input_name}" checked="checked" value="{option_id}"/> {option_name} {if price_mod_val} ({price_mod}) {/if}</label>
    </div>
    {/modifier_options}
```

This selects the last modifier but would like it to be the first.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option already for this in the docs:
https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/product_tag.html#if_option_first

Thought I'd post the answer anyway.

```
{modifier_options}
    <div class="large-6 columns">
        <label><input type="radio" name="{modifier_input_name}" {if option_first}checked="checked"{/if} value="{option_id}"/> {option_name} {if price_mod_val} ({price_mod}) {/if}</label>
    </div>
{/modifier_options}
```